# Is AOT compilation helpful for Electron applications

Tags: angular, electron, angular2-aot, electron-forge

I am currently building an Electron application with Angular using [electron-forge](https://beta.electronforge.io/) tool and I am in the process of compiling the Angular code in order to bundle it. I started to implement AOT compilation but I got stuck because I have not find a way to use component-relative paths, that AOT requires (if interested, more on [this](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-forge-templates/issues/25) issue).

On the other hand, I was wondering if does it worth to make AOT compilation for an Electron application. As, Angular Official Documentation states in the [AOT compilation cookbook](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/aot-compiler.html):

[image]

Most of the above reasons have to do when using a browser client. One can tell that **Smaller Angular framework download size** could be a benefit and this really depends on the application in question.

Comment: How do you count that 'Most of the above reasons'? Electron IS a browser client. You don't have to care about traffic because it's local (and AoT doesn't necessarily reduces traffic at all). But otherwise all the points are still valid. Case closed, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is definitely a good idea.

@estus When you say

> and AOT doesn't necessarily reduces traffic at all

This is not true.

When you compile your app using `AOT` (with `angular-cli` or `webpack`), angular's compiler is removed from the bundle (**bundle from 600+kb to 300kb**).

**The bigger is your app, the more angular's compiler will have to parse the HTML templates.** So yes, even for an app running inside Electron (with local files) it make sense to use `AOT` to **reduce scripting and thus, startup time.**

Answer (score 0):

AOT will produce "optimization-friendly" JS code that will be consumed by JIT compiler (JS to Machine code) inside the browser (chromium). So for run-time performance i believe there will be some improvement.

For startup time it depends on all the total payload i think. As far as I understand AOT sometimes will produce bigger or smaller sizes, it really depends.

Answer (score 0):

It is good idea to implement **AOT** in Angular 2 Application as it **pre compile** all your imported/registered files and **bundle in few files**, which enhance/improve your web request performance.

And it convert all your typescript code to JavaScript code with **minification** hence file size minimize, few file restrict file request on page load and result quick response from browser.

I have also implemented AOT in my app and it works like cherry on cake.

Answer (score 0):

AOT compilation with Angular which uses CLI command `ng build` to precompile and bundle all the files into the folder `dist/project_name` and then serve from this folder. As you have mentioned you were using electron-forge, which uses JIT compilation and doesn't touch the build folder from angular's AOT compilation at all. So AOT compilation doesn't help with electron application.